# Npm: git authentication to install package

Tags: npm

I'm trying to install `angular-devkit/build-angular` package:

```
$ npm install angular-devkit/build-angular
```

My current `npm config` is:

```
https-proxy = "http://10.49.1.1:8080/"
proxy = "http://10.49.1.1:8080/"
registry = "https://setools.t-systems.es/nexus/repository/npm-all/"
strict-ssl = false
```

I'm able to install `events` package:

```
$ npm install events
+ events@3.2.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.399s
```

As you can see, it's installed correctly.

However, I'm getting this message when I'm trying to install `angular-devkit/build-angular`:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular-devkit/build-angular.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Permission denied, please try again.
npm ERR! Permission denied, please try again.
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `@` in your installation command. Use this:

```
$ npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Without the `@`, `npm` can't make sense of `angular-devkit/build-angular`, tries to guess a GitHub URL, and guesses wrong.